# Test custom route error handling with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a rails 4 api application in which I capture all missing routes like this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
   # matchers ...
  end

  # catch all undefined paths and redirect them to the errors controller
  match "*path", to: "errors#routing_error", via: :all
end
```

With a simple click through test, this seems to work like a charm, however I'd like to write
an rspec test for this behaviour.

In my Rspec spec I try the following:

```
it "should capture non existing action" do
  get '/api/non-existing-action', format: :json  #Note that non-existing-action is not defined in the routes.rb
  #expectations come here
end
```

The problem is that Rspec seem to catch the routing error before the router and raises a default error like this one

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
No route matches {:action=>"/api/non-existing-action", :controller=>"api/api", :format=>:json}`

So my question is: Is there a way to tell Rspec that it should let my router handle the non existing path, so that I can expect the error response from my errors controller?

Comment: have you tried the [route_to](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-4/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher) matcher? Does it still give the error?

Comment: Thanks, but I get the exact same error

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: no, unfortunately not